# open excel document from web page using c#

Tags: c#

I am using selenium application to download an excel file from web. The file is downloaded in read only format, that is it doesn't gets saved after downloading. But once it downloads before opening the excel throws a security warning in which it has 2 buttons-enable and disable. Since I am coding in c#, I want c# to handle that window.

That is I want c# to click on "Enable" button of that excel sheet. Is it possible?? Any comments would be really appreciated..

thanks

Comment: One way you could solve this is to make the location you open it from a "Trusted Location"

Comment: Thanks Paul Grimshaw: But how could I do that, if I am downloading it from a sharepoint location??

Answer (score 1):

To add a trusted location in Excel:

1. Click the Microsoft Office Button Button image, and then click Excel Options.
2. Click Trust Center, click Trust Center Settings, and then click Trusted Locations.
3. If you want to create a trusted location that is not local to your computer, select the Allow trusted locations on my network (not recommended) check box.
4. Click Add new location.

(from http://office.microsoft.com/en-za/excel-help/create-remove-or-change-a-trusted-location-for-your-files-HA010031999.aspx#BM12)

Comment: Since I am opening that document in read only file, I cant add that path(even though it is in my local machine).My path seems to be C:\Users\%user%\AppData\Local\Temp\filename.dll-2.jqy

Comment: I see your point. This will stop that from happening, but obviously opens up a security risk: In Excel (2010), click _Options > Trust Center > Trust Center Settings > Protected View_ and unselect the top option "_Enable Protected View for files originating from the Internet_"

Comment: I was busy editing my previous comment, so you may not have seen the full message

Comment: It seems to be because this is a data connection, and not just an unsecure spreadhseet. The setting you need is under "_Trust Center Settings > External Content > Security settings for Data Connections_", but again, it's opening a big security hole.

Answer (score 0):

I am not that familiar with selenium, but you could use native SendKeys or [simular interface](http://inputsimulator.codeplex.com/) to navigate the popup.

A different approach could be using the windows automation api.

Comment: :Is simular interface a package which can be included in my code??But how does that solve my issue since I am opening excel doc from sharepoint list??